# Autogenerate a PDF or image of all the database tables and columns in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, image, schema

I want to be able to create a PDF or an image of a MySQL database. It should have one box per table and each box should list all the columns in the table. I don't need lines going between various forgein keys or show info on default types or even the type of the column.

Is there such an open source programme to do this?

Comment: [dbForge Studio for MySQL Enterprise Edition](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html#documenter) and [dbForge Documenter for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/documenter/) will help you. Both shareware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no one good way to do this

Answer (score 3):

You may try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to create a diagram by importing the sql create statements of your database.

Answer (score 2):

It's not open-source and not free (license is 99 USD):

[**DBDesc**](http://www.dbdesc.com/)

> dbdesc is a powerful tool to help you
>   document your databases. It can
>   produce detailed documents describing
>   your databases.
>
> [...]
>
> Now dbdesc includes a built-in report
>   engine and report viewer to easily
>   browse database documentation. This
>   report can be exported to PDF.

Here is a table containing all [features for the different database platforms](http://www.dbdesc.com/features.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say just how much detail you want but have you considered using the MySQL "show tables;" command? You can use it to create a chart of the fields but it doesn't tell you anything other than the field name.